# How to get the previously added layer information for getGetFeatureInfoUrl?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, wms, getfeatureinfo

I am able to fetch the getGetFeatureInfoUrl for the currently selected layer, is it possible to fetch the last added layer FeatureInfo on the map?

My code currently is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>WMS GetFeatureInfo (Tile Layer)</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v3.19.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v3.19.1/build/ol.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Disaster</label>
      <select id="dict" class="form-control" onchange="loadfloodlayer(this.id);">
        <option>Select disaster</option>
        <option value="guntur">guntur</option>
        <option value="krishna">krishna</option> 
        <option value="prakasam">prakasam</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <div id="info">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="info2">&nbsp;</div>
    <script>
      var wmsSource = new ol.source.TileWMS( {
        url: 'http://ndem.nrsc.gov.in/geoserver/wms',
        params: {'LAYERS': 'ndem50k:stateadmin50census2011'}
      });
      var wmsLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: wmsSource
      });
      var mapcenter = [79.60,23.44];
      var view = new ol.View({
        projection: 'EPSG:4326',
        center: mapcenter,
        zoom: 5,
        extent: [66.2329, 7.68083, 98.2223, 39.03874],
        maxZoom:16,
        minZoom: 4
      });
      var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [wmsLayer],
        target: 'map',
        view: view
      });
      function loadfloodlayer(idd1) {
        hint = "manjula:";
        hitn = hint + $('#dict').val();
        alert(hitn);
        var  railvar = new ol.source.TileWMS({
            url: 'http://localhost:8089/geoserver/manjula/wms',
            params: {LAYERS: hitn}
        });
        var wmsLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: railvar
      });
      map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = '';
        document.getElementById('info2').innerHTML = '';
        var viewResolution = /** @type {number} */ (view.getResolution());
        var url2 = wmsSource.getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
          evt.coordinate, viewResolution, 'EPSG:4326',
          {'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html'});
          var url = railvar.getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
            evt.coordinate, viewResolution, 'EPSG:4326',
            {'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html'});
          if (url) {
            document.getElementById('info').innerHTML =
            '<iframe style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="' + url + '"></iframe>';
          }
          if (url2) {
            document.getElementById('info2').innerHTML =
            '<iframe style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="' + url2 + '"></iframe>';
          }
      });
      map.on('pointermove', function(evt) {
        if (evt.dragging) {
          return;
        }
        var pixel = map.getEventPixel(evt.originalEvent);
        var hit = map.forEachLayerAtPixel(pixel, function() {
          return true;
        });
        map.getTargetElement().style.cursor = hit ? 'pointer' : '';
      });
      map.addLayer(wmsLayer); 
      }  
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you mean layers that are in the same WMS service, or layers that are in different services?

Answer (score 1):

> I am able to fetch the getGetFeatureInfoUrl for the currently selected
>   layer, is it possible to fetch the last added layer FeatureInfo on the
>   map?

If the layers are from the same service then yes; in any GetFeatureInfo request you can return information from more the one layer, the QUERY_LAYERS parameter defines the layers to be queried, so it's either a single layer name or a list of layer names (separated by a comma).

So for the current map (the result of a GetMap request) in your OpenLayers  client you can make a GetFeatureInfo request for the layer shown, for another layer (the previous layer), or indeed for multiple layers.